# How get html input value on php

Tags: javascript, php, html

I need to store some variable which I can extract from javascript and later need to use on php when submit the form.

So I have created  input field on html like

**HTML**

```
  <input type="hidden" name="videoname_var" id="videoname_var" method="get"/>
```

And on init I have set the value of this input from java script

**JS**

```
document.getElementById("videoname_var").value = VIDEO_NAME_;
```

And later on submit, from php I am accessing the value like,

```
$videoname = $_GET['videoname_var'];
```

But the value of  $videoname is always null,

Anything wrong on this approach?.

Edit:

Here is the from,

```
<form id=form_id enctype="multipart/form-data" encoding='multipart/form-data' method='post' >
 <input class=" button1" type="submit" name="Submit" value="Upload">
 <input type="hidden" name="videoname_var" id="videoname_var" />
</form>
```

And I am setting the value from java script $(document).ready() like

```
document.getElementById("videoname_var").value = VIDEO_NAME_;
```

And at on submit button click

This php was executing

```
if (isset($_FILES['file']))
{
 $videoname = $_GET['videoname_var'];
}
```

Comment: this is just wrong `<input type="hidden" name="videoname_var" id="videoname_var" method="get"/>`

Comment: If you set the value from JS you have to send it to PHP somehow. Are you doing a form submit, or AJAX?

Comment: No I am not submitting.

Comment: are you actually making a GET request in your javascript?

Comment: `method="get"` must be in the FORM element, not in INPUT. Can you post the complete form?

Comment: @Igor True, or in an ajax call.

Comment: So how can I resolve the issue.

Comment: This must be a duplicate...

Comment: Post a more complete example of code: the form  and the submit function if you did it with javascript.

Comment: @CodeDezk you can solve this buy posting your real full code

Comment: @Igor I have edited the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this for form not input

```
method="get"
```

like this

```
<form method="get" action="">
  <input type="hidden" value="videoname_var value" name="videoname_var" id="videoname_var" />
</form>
```

Comment: I am unsure why this got downvoted; given the other answer that got upvoted being the same. Not my dv here btw. Edit: the downvote seems to have been retracted.

Comment: If you're using GET you do not have to set a method because GET is the default method for a form.

Answer (score 1):

You have to set your form method in the `form` element `<form method="get|post">` but not in any other form's element.

The `method` attribute of the `form` element tells the browser how to send form data to a web server:

```
<form method="get">
...
</form>
```

Note that `get` is the default value and appends the form-data to the form's action URL in name/value pairs: URL?name=value&name=value

Comment: If you're using GET you do not have to set a method because GET is the default method for a form.